# Как получить доступ к protected свойствам класса?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь вытащить значение из этого набора, как это можно сделать, не прибегая к `json` и `xml`?

Мне нужно достать вин-номер `[vin:protected]` и бренд `[brand:protected]`

Вот `print_r($car)`:

```
Company\CMS\Module\Car\Model\Car Object
(
[carStatus:protected] => 0
[creatorUserID:protected] => 22635
[vin:protected] => Z8NAJL10060639823
[year:protected] => 2018
[additionalInfo:protected] => 
[price:protected] => 667000
[discount:protected] => 100000
[paymentPerMonth:protected] => 14091
[arrModelFiles:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[objColor:protected] =>  Company\CMS\Module\Color\Model\Color Object
    (
        [name:protected] => белый
        [filename:protected] => Crystal White.png
        [ID:protected] => 1036
    )

[objConfiguration:protected] =>  Company\CMS\Module\Configuration\Model\Configuration Object
    (
        [model:protected] =>  Company\CMS\Module\Model\Model\Model Object
            (
                [brand:protected] => Company\CMS\Module\Brand\Model\Brand Object
                    (
                        [name:protected] => Nissan
                        [logofilename:protected] => logo_nissan.png
                        [ID:protected] => 97
                    )
```

Код Маппера

```
public function selectForView($ID) {
    $query = <<<"SQL"
SELECT
c.`ID` AS carID,
c.`vin` AS carVIN,
`carYear`,
c.`price` AS carPrice,
`carDiscount`,
c.`paymentPerMonth` AS carPaymentPerMonth,
`carAdditionalInfo`,
`c`.`creatorUserID`,

cf.`ID` AS confId,
cf.`volume` AS confVolume,
cf.`horsepower` AS confHorsepower,

m.`ID` AS modelID,
m.`name` AS modelName,
`modelDescription`,

b.`ID` AS brandID,
b.`name` AS brandName,
b.`logofilename` AS brandLogoFileName,

c.`colorID`, `colorName`, `colorFileName`,
`bodyTypeID`, `bodyTypeName`,
`gearboxTypeID`, `gearboxTypeName`,
`driveTypeID`, `driveTypeName`,
`engineTypeID`, `engineTypeName`,

e.`equipID`, e.`equipName`, e.`equipExterior`, e.`equipInterior`,
e.`equipClimate`, e.`equipMultimedia`, e.`equipComfort`, e.`equipSecurity`
FROM `cars` AS c
JOIN `configurations` AS cf ON c.`configurationID` = cf.`ID`
JOIN `models` AS m ON cf.`modelID` = m.`ID`
JOIN `brands` AS b ON m.`brandID` = b.`ID`
JOIN `colors` ON c.`colorID` = colors.`colorID`
LEFT JOIN `equipment` AS e ON c.`equipID` = e.`equipID`
NATURAL JOIN `bodyTypes`
NATURAL JOIN `gearboxTypes`
NATURAL JOIN `driveTypes`
NATURAL JOIN `engineTypes`
WHERE
c.`ID` = :carID
SQL;

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':carID', $ID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!$row) {
        return null;
    }

    $car = new Car($ID);
    $car->constructFromRow($row);
    $car->setArrModelFiles($this->getImages($car->getModelID()));

    return $car;
}
```

Код Контроллера

```
 public function view($ID) {
    $car = $this->mapper->selectForView($ID);

    $this->template->setName('carView.twig');
    $this->template->add('tplStyleV2', true);

    $this->template->add('thisURL', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $this->template->add('currentUserHasAdminRole', $this->currentUserHasAdminRole);
    $this->template->add('currentUserHasDealerRole', $this->currentUserHasDealerRole);
    $this->template->add('currentUserHasCustomerRole', $this->currentUserHasCustomerRole);
    $this->template->add('car', $car);

    $url = 'https://newanycar.ru' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $metatags = get_meta_tags($url);
    $cyrnams = $metatags['cyrnames'];

    $vinnumb = $metatags['vinnumber'];


    $vinnumber = substr($vinnumb, 0, 13);

    $vinnumberskr = $vinnumber . '****';

    $cyr = array(
       "a"=>"а","b"=>"б","v"=>"в","g"=>"г","d"=>"д","e"=>"е","yo"=>"ё", "j"=>"ж","z"=>"з","i"=>"и","i"=>"й","k"=>"к", "l"=>"л","m"=>"м","n"=>"н","o"=>"о","p"=>"п","r"=>"р","s"=>"с","t"=>"т", "y"=>"у","f"=>"ф","h"=>"х","c"=>"ц", "ch"=>"ч","sh"=>"ш","sh"=>"щ","i"=>"ы","e"=>"е","u"=>"у","yu"=>"е","ya"=>"я","A"=>"А","B"=>"Б", "V"=>"В","G"=>"Г","D"=>"Д", "E"=>"Е","Yo"=>"Ё","J"=>"Ж","Z"=>"З","I"=>"И","I"=>"Й","K"=>"К","L"=>"Л","M"=>"М", "N"=>"Н","O"=>"О","P"=>"П", "R"=>"Р","S"=>"С","T"=>"Т","Y"=>"Ю","F"=>"Ф","H"=>"Х","C"=>"Ц","Ch"=>"Ч","Sh"=>"Ш", "Sh"=>"Щ","I"=>"Ы","E"=>"Е", "U"=>"У","Ya"=>"Я","'"=>"ь","'"=>"Ь","''"=>"ъ","''"=>"Ъ","j"=>"ї","i"=>"и","g"=>"ґ", "ye"=>"є","J"=>"Ї","I"=>"І", "G"=>"Ґ","YE"=>"Є",

      );//$vinnumb var_dump($car)

    $CyrillicNames = strtr($cyrnams, $cyr);
    $this->template->add('cyr', $CyrillicNames);
    $this->template->add('vinnew', $vinnumberskr);

    return $this->template->render();
```

Да, вот код класса, надеюсь это как то упростит

```
protected $carStatus = 0;
protected $creatorUserID = 0;
protected $vin = '';
protected $year = 0;
protected $additionalInfo = '';
protected $price = 0;               
protected $discount = 0;            
protected $paymentPerMonth = 0;
protected $arrModelFiles = [];

protected $objColor = null;
protected $objConfiguration = null;
protected $objEquipment = null;



public function __construct($ID = 0) {
    parent::__construct($ID);
    $this->objColor = new Color(0);
    $this->objConfiguration = new Configuration(0, 0);
    $this->objEquipment = new Equipment(0);
}



public function constructFromRow($row) {
    if (isset($row['carStatus'])) {
        $this->carStatus = $row['carStatus'];
    }
    if (isset($row['carCreatorUserID'])) {
        $this->creatorUserID = $row['carCreatorUserID'];
    }
    if (isset($row['carVIN'])) {
        $this->vin = $row['carVIN'];
    }
    if (isset($row['carYear'])) {
        $this->year = $row['carYear'];
    }
    if (isset($row['carAdditionalInfo'])) {
        $this->additionalInfo = $row['carAdditionalInfo'];
    }
    if (isset($row['colorID'])) {
        $this->objColor = new Color($row['colorID']);
        $this->objColor->constructFromRow($row);
    }
    if (isset($row['confId'])) {
        $this->objConfiguration = new Configuration($row['confId'], 0);
        $this->objConfiguration->constructFromRow($row);
    }
    if (isset($row['equipID'])) {
        $this->objEquipment = new Equipment($row['equipID']);
        $this->objEquipment->constructFromRow($row);
    }
    if (isset($row['carPrice'])) {
        $this->price = intval($row['carPrice']);
    }
    if (isset($row['carDiscount'])) {
        $this->discount = intval($row['carDiscount']);
    }
    if (isset($row['carPaymentPerMonth'])) {
        $this->paymentPerMonth = $row['carPaymentPerMonth'];
    }

    if (isset($row['creatorUserID'])) {
        $this->creatorUserID = $row['creatorUserID'];
    }


}
```

Comment: Наверно в классе `Car` должен быть метод для получения значений свойств класса

Comment: Должен быть, но его там попросту нет

Comment: дак сделайте, код то в наличии

Comment: Можно ли этого как то избежать, прибегая к стандартным способом извлечения данных из подобного массива?

Comment: Покажите код класса

Comment: Это не массив, это объект и так просто извлечь не получится

Comment: Вас просили предоставить код класса `Company\CMS\Module\Car\Model\Car` а не контроллера и маппера

Comment: впрочем, скорее всего, методы для доступа к свойствам реализованы не в классе `Car` а в каком-то из его родительских классов

Comment: Ну а вдруг) можно хоть посмотреть от чего наследуется

Comment: Изучайте родительские классы. В каком нибудь базовом классе моделей должен быть реализован доступ к свойствам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть класс с `protected` свойствами, к которым нужно получит доступ. При этом, допустим,у нас нет возможности изменения кода класса, или создания и использования класса наследника, имеющего в свою очередь доступ к `protected` полям.

```
class Car {
    protected $vin = "Z8NAJL10060639823";
    protected $brand = "Жигули";
}
```

**Очевидно, все прочие варианты (кроме изменения кода и наследования) это "костыли".**

Вот  некоторые из них:

Вы можете привести объект к ассоциативному массиву, и получить доступ к полю. 
У соответствующего ключа будет префикс `\0*\0`

```
$cArray = (array)$car;
$vin = $cArray["\0*\0vin"];
```

---

Вы можете использовать анонимную функцию, передав ей ваш объект как контекст для доступа и подмены `this` (для пхп 7)

```
$getProperties = function($props){
    $result = [];
    foreach($props as $p){
        $result[$p] = $this->$p;
    }
    return $result;
};

$props = $getProperties->call($car, ['vin']);
$vin = $props['vin'];
```

---

Можете использовать рефлексию

```
$r = new ReflectionClass($car);
$prop = $r->getProperty('vin');
$prop->setAccessible(true);
$vin = $prop->getValue($car);
```

---

Как уже писалось в комментариях, где то в недрах иерархии наследования вашей модели есть методы получения доступа к защищенным полям класса. Поскольку мы не видим код этих классов-предков то сказать как конкретно они работают нельзя (но по к гадалке не ходи, там все основано на магических методах). Так же мы с вами выяснили, что в шаблоне доступ к переменной осуществляется следующим образом: `{{ car.Vin }}`.
 Поскольку  просто доступ к `$car->Vin` дает нам пустой результат при выполнении кода, то следует обратиться к [документации twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html) и посмотреть, как он интерпретирует подобный синтаксис.
Итак:

> For convenience's sake `foo.bar` does the following things on the PHP layer:
>
> - check if `foo` is an `array` and `bar` a valid element;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an `object`, check that `bar` is a valid property;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an `object`, check that `bar` is a valid method (even if bar is the constructor - use __construct() instead);
> - if not, and if `foo` is an `object`, check that `getBar` is a valid method;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an `object`, check that `isBar` is a valid method;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `hasBar` is a valid method;
> - if not, return a `null` value.

Отсюда можно сделать вывод. Твиг сам по себе выводит значение. То есть его правила срабатывают. Поскольку переменная у нас не объект, а свойство `Vin` у нас не валидно, то далее твиг проверяет метод `$car->getVin()`. Остальные проверки `isBar/hasBar`, не особо логичны.

Так что, `$car->getVin()` вам в помощь.

Comment: Если я, например, воспользуюсь методом привидения к ассоциативному массиву, как я могу достать данные из вложенных массивов?

Comment: Это что за метод привидения к ассоциативному массиву класса?

Comment: @МаксимНеделько вместо того чтобы тратить время на поиск нужного костыля, лучше как уже не раз сказано, изучить код родительских классов модели. Не поверю, что там нет таких методов. Но более простой вариант - открыть соответствующий twig-шаблон `carView.twig`, там ведь эти данные на страницу выводятся? вот и посмотрите как они там берутся

Comment: будет там у вам какой нить `$car._vin` или `$car.getVin()` и т.п.

Comment: Верно, всё выводится, но выводится в стиле {{car.Vin}} - в виде внешней переменной, которая отсылается объектом на этот шаблон

Comment: что еще за внешняя? написано в шаблоне `car.Vin` вот и получайте в коде `$car->Vin`. Этот тот же самый объект переданный в шаблон в строке `$this->template->add('car', $car);`

Comment: Суть понял, только такая конструкция в коде почему то не работает, и не только с этим значением. Так же $car->Vin, $car->Year, $car->ModelName - возращает null. Но шаблон не ломается

Comment: @МаксимНеделько дополнил ответ. пробуйте `$car->getVin()` должно сработать.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, разобрался, спасибо

Comment: @МаксимНеделько если мой ответ вам помог, то ткните там  галку [Принять](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). И таки, что было то, `getVin()` ?

Comment: Да, просто через вызов публичной функции $car->getVin();

Comment: @МаксимНеделько формально, это не публичная функция. Как видно из описания класса `Car` такой функции там нет. Это реализовано [с помощью метода `__call`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) где то на родительском уровне наследования.

Answer (score 1):

Так как это не просто массив, а объект, то получить можно только публичные свойства, а у вас они - **protected**, поэтому нужно пользоваться методом - get-ером

Comment: Интересно, то есть только через метод?

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в класс `Car` геттеры для нужных полей

```
    Class Car {
      public function getVin() {
        return $this->vin;
      }
      public function getBrand() {
        return $this->brand;
      }
       ...
    }
```